# Python 3.9 crashes when using the interactive prompt with virualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on Centos 7.8.2003 and compiled Python 3.9 locally.  For the most part, it works fine, however, when I try to run the interactive prompt after being in a virualenv, it crashes.  If I'm not in a virtualenv, it works fine.  It also works fine if I'm in a jupyter while still in the virual env.

These are the steps I followed to compile and install Python:

```
# i know I don't need all of these for building python, but this is everything I installed for other things
yum install httpd httpd-devel mysql mysql-devel mod_wsgi perl-devel asciidoc xmlto autoconf gcc zlib-devel gettext mod_ssl python-devel python-lxml libxml2-devel libxslt1-devel libxslt-devel ncurses-devel patch mod_wsgi  memcached redis gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel sqlite-devel xz-devel -y
curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.0/Python-3.9.0.tgz
tar -xzf Python-3.9.0.tgz
cd Python-3.9.0
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib"
make altinstall
```

and then did this to create the virtualenv and source it:

```
python3.9 -m venv /opt/venv
. /opt/venv/bin/activate
```

then i run the interactive shell and regardless of what I put there, it crashes

```
(venv) [root@billing-dev ~]# python
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov  5 2020, 14:59:33)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0
    *** Error in `python': free(): invalid size: 0x00007f62b36034f0 ***
    ======= Backtrace: =========
    /lib64/libc.so.6(+0x81299)[0x7f62b1ff1299]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(PyOS_Readline+0xf6)[0x7f62b2f2d8d6]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x954e7)[0x7f62b2f2f4e7]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x95bc8)[0x7f62b2f2fbc8]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x97ed9)[0x7f62b2f31ed9]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x75ec9)[0x7f62b2f0fec9]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x900da)[0x7f62b2f2a0da]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x76bf0)[0x7f62b2f10bf0]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x76f36)[0x7f62b2f10f36]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(+0x1ffb67)[0x7f62b3099b67]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags+0x86)[0x7f62b3099d86]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(PyRun_AnyFileExFlags+0x3e)[0x7f62b309a6ae]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(Py_RunMain+0x8f3)[0x7f62b30b9cc3]
    /usr/local/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0(Py_BytesMain+0x4f)[0x7f62b30b9fef]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f62b1f92555]
    python[0x40067e]
    ======= Memory map: ========
    00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 8577122                            /usr/local/bin/python3.9
    00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 8577122                            /usr/local/bin/python3.9
    00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 ca:01 8577122                            /usr/local/bin/python3.9
    0217c000-02267000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
    7f62a4000000-7f62a4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    7f62a4021000-7f62a8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
    7f62aacb8000-7f62aaccd000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 397                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7f62aaccd000-7f62aaecc000 ---p 00015000 ca:01 397                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7f62aaecc000-7f62aaecd000 r--p 00014000 ca:01 397                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7f62aaecd000-7f62aaece000 rw-p 00015000 ca:01 397                        /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
    7f62aaece000-7f62aaef3000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 89309                      /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
    7f62aaef3000-7f62ab0f3000 ---p 00025000 ca:01 89309                      /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
    7f62ab0f3000-7f62ab0f7000 r--p 00025000 ca:01 89309                      /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
    7f62ab0f7000-7f62ab0f8000 rw-p 00029000 ca:01 89309                      /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5.9
    7f62ab0f8000-7f62ab11e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 89299                      /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5.9
    7f62ab11e000-7f62ab31d000 ---p 00026000 ca:01 89299                      /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5.9
    7f62ab31d000-7f62ab31e000 r--p 00025000 ca:01 89299                      /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5.9
    7f62ab31e000-7f62ab31f000 rw-p 00026000 ca:01 89299                      /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5.9
    7f62ab31f000-7f62ab35b000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 113300066                  /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/readline.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab35b000-7f62ab55b000 ---p 0003c000 ca:01 113300066                  /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/readline.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab55b000-7f62ab55d000 r--p 0003c000 ca:01 113300066                  /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/readline.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab55d000-7f62ab564000 rw-p 0003e000 ca:01 113300066                  /opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/readline.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab564000-7f62ab625000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    7f62ab625000-7f62ab629000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 104899278                  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab629000-7f62ab828000 ---p 00004000 ca:01 104899278                  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab828000-7f62ab829000 r--p 00003000 ca:01 104899278                  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab829000-7f62ab82a000 rw-p 00004000 ca:01 104899278                  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    7f62ab82a000-7f62b1d6d000 r--p 00000000 ca:01 12820339                   /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
    7f62b1d6d000-7f62b1d6f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 68232                      /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
    7f62b1d6f000-7f62b1f6e000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 68232                      /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
    7f62b1f6e000-7f62b1f6f000 r--p 00001000 ca:01 68232                      /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
    7f62b1f6f000-7f62b1f70000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 68232                      /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
    7f62b1f70000-7f62b2133000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 111722                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7f62b2133000-7f62b2333000 ---p 001c3000 ca:01 111722                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7f62b2333000-7f62b2337000 r--p 001c3000 ca:01 111722                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7f62b2337000-7f62b2339000 rw-p 001c7000 ca:01 111722                     /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
    7f62b2339000-7f62b233e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
    7f62b233e000-7f62b243f000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 111730                     /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7f62b243f000-7f62b263e000 ---p 00101000 ca:01 111730                     /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7f62b263e000-7f62b263f000 r--p 00100000 ca:01 111730                     /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7f62b263f000-7f62b2640000 rw-p 00101000 ca:01 111730                     /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
    7f62b2640000-7f62b2642000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 88242                      /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
    7f62b2642000-7f62b2841000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 88242                      /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
    7f62b2841000-7f62b2842000 r--p 00001000 ca:01 88242                      /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
    7f62b2842000-7f62b2843000 rw-p 00002000 ca:01 88242                      /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
    7f62b2843000-7f62b2845000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 111728                     /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
    7f62b2845000-7f62b2a45000 ---p 00002000 ca:01 111728                     /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
    7f62b2a45000-7f62b2a46000 r--p 00002000 ca:01 111728                     /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
    7f62b2a46000-7f62b2a47000 rw-p 00003000 ca:01 111728                     /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
    7f62b2a47000-7f62b2a5e000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 88232                      /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.soAborted
```

when not in an activated shell, all works fine:

```
[root@billing-dev ~]# python3.9
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov  5 2020, 14:59:33)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0
0
>>>
```

Comment: This is likely a bug, since Python3.9 was just released today.

Comment: Do you create the virtual environment with `virtualenv` or with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)? The latter is part of the standard library.

Comment: i had the virtualenv creation command, but the editor didn't show it.  it's there now.  I don't think this is a bug with python.  I remember seeing this when building for a previous version of Python, but didn't work to troubleshoot it then.  I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the way I built it.